# iptables as gateway and POP3 SMTP ports

Tags: iptables, gateway

when trying to open the ports 110 and 25 in my iptables for outlook-only users, i cant do it except by forwarding as such:

```
-I FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -i eth1 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

but doing so allows the rest of the users in my lan to bypass my squid proxy. whats the proper syntax for these forwarding commands to just pen ports 110 and 25?

EDIT:

this is my current iptables file that im directly configuring. it works for now but im sure its far from perfect. currently users with no explicit proxy server cannot connect to the internet. outlook ports are working.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Fri Mar  9 13:59:24 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [25448:1902369]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [29:1625]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [786:56571]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar  9 13:59:24 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Fri Mar  9 13:59:24 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [1:68]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LOGDROP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j LOGDROP 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5190 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A LOGDROP -j LOG 
-A LOGDROP -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar  9 13:59:24 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's start it again from the beginning.

Set your FORWARD chaing to ACCEPT (just in case)

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Clear your FORWARD chain

`iptables -F FORWARD`

Allow out your users to check smtp and pop

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
```

**DO NOT** add -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT as this is **unsecure**.

Let the responses in for these questions

`iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

set your FORWARD chain policy back to DROP

`iptables -P FORWARD DROP`

Now, the first part should work. If not, then ip_forward is not enables.

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Regarding the reboot problem.
Iptables commands are not persistent, so you have to use a script, or use your Linux distribution built-in iptables administration script.

The easiest and less elegant way is to run this command when you are ok with your configuration and working.

`iptables-save >/etc/myfirewall_config`

And hook up and initscript which loads it back when booting up

`iptables-restore </etc/myfirewall_config`

Done.

If you still havve problems after all of these, post your NAT table (iptables -t nat -vnL)

Comment: i see. if i were to add the stateful rule and add the forwarding rules for ports pop3 and smtp ports only to specified ip addresses as Jiri below suggested, would that still be insecure?

Comment: If you add Jiri's rule and the stateful and delete what i suggested then iy is going to be secure

Comment: added the stateful and jiri's rules and everything works fine. thanks to both of u. should i have accepted jiri's answer instead?

Comment: Send the output of iptables -vnL and i can tell

Comment: ip forwarding is enabled Gabor,its set to 1

Comment: Gabor thanks for bearing with me! im not using iptables commands, im editing iptables file directly so the reboot thing is puzzling me. however everytime a configuration works i actually do try to reboot and make sure everything is still working, but the next day it would stop working. witchcraft maybe. anywhose ive edited my original post, please check it and let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

'-I FORWARD -i eth1 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT' enables/opens access from (probably) yours egress iface to internal lan.

for allowing outgoing connection use - 'iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.11.0/24 -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT'.

be aware that enabling outgoing connection just like that is wrong, you give virus/worms/trojans to connect to internet via those ports. restrict it by specifying exact destination IP, of force users to use internal smtp server for outgoing connection with AUTH enabled.

if they need remote pop3, download mail via pop3 to a server inside your network and inform your users to use internal pop3 "mirror" copy.

there are also some pop3 proxies or some mail client can run pop3/smtp via proxy...

Comment: i get a syntax error when applying that -D rule

Comment: ah, sorry i pasted bad line, '-D' was deleting command :D OK one is '-I' (insert) or '-A' (append).

Comment: no worries jiri! but i tried both -I and -A and it didnt work. i tried similar syntax before i posted here. what are we missing?

Comment: no idea, paste an error, works for me